# Можно ли в пользовательское меню послать функцию, которая принимает параметры на вход?

Tags: google-apps-script

Работаю с google apps script, понадобилось в пользовательское меню добавить функцию, которая принимает параметры на вход. В официальной документации не нашла ничего. Может кто сталкивался с подобной задачей?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно, но зачем? Да и что значит "пеедать параметры", если вы вызываете пункт меню с именем функции, а не с самой функцией. Самое правильно в этом случае -- это предоставить для вызываемой функции контекст, который она сможет прочитать и обработать согласно настройкам, которые можно хранить где угодно: в свойствах пользователя, в кеше, на отдельном листе Таблицы и т.п.

Единственный полезный вариант -- это генерация динамичекского меню, напрмиер, из билиотеки.

Путь требуется вызывать функцию-обработчик события меню `dynamicMenuItem`

```js
/* exported dynamicMenuItem */
function dynamicMenuItem(e) {
  var caption = e.item.caption;
  var order = e.order;
  Browser.msgBox(Utilities.formatString('Был нажат %sй пункт меню: %s', order + 1, caption));
}
```

Необходимо заранее зарегистрировать функции вызова в окружении `globalThis`

```js
(function (self) {
  DYNAMIC_MENU_CONFIG.forEach(function (item, i) {
    self[item.functionName + i] = function () {
      return self[item.functionName]({ item: item, order: i });
    };
  });
})(this);
```

Настройки меню берем из глобальной переменной

```js
/**
 * @typedef {{
 *   caption: string,
 *   functionName: string
 * }} GSRU.DynamicMenu
 */

const DYNAMIC_MENU_CONFIG = [
  {
    caption: 'Пункт меню 1',
    functionName: 'dynamicMenuItem',
  },
  {
    caption: 'Пункт меню 2',
    functionName: 'dynamicMenuItem',
  },
  {
    caption: 'Пункт меню 3',
    functionName: 'dynamicMenuItem',
  },
];
```

Обновление и получение меню

```js
/* exported getDynamicMenu_ */
/**
 *
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Base.Ui} ui
 * @param {string} name
 */
function getDynamicMenu_(ui, name) {
  var menu = ui.createMenu(name);

  configDynamicMenu_(menu, DYNAMIC_MENU_CONFIG);

  return menu;
}

/**
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Base.Menu} menu
 * @param {GSRU.DynamicMenu[]} config
 */
function configDynamicMenu_(menu, config) {
  config.forEach(function (item, i) {
    menu.addItem(item.caption, item.functionName + i);
  });
}
```

Добавдение меню в текущую Таблицу

```js
   .addSubMenu(getDynamicMenu_(SpreadsheetApp.getUi(), 'Динамическое меню'))
```

Рабочий пример в Таблице https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KN2SuXbHN5ETss9Sj4WOTOIyxuxHUpuI_8GFewwtkBc/edit?usp=sharing

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Иными словами, меню ссылается на название функции, и если она с параметрами, то всё равно будет работать?

Comment: То, что вы пишите в JS в функции параметры никак не влияет на вызов этой функции. Хоть обпишитесь, вызов будет возможен без параметров. Меню не передает параметры в фунцию, поэтому параметризировать эту чатсь бессмыслено. Обратите внимание, что вы так и не ответили на мой вопрос, зачем вам это?

Comment: Извиняюсь. Есть таблица, где работает вся компания, но автор этой таблицы один отдел. Зада в том, чтобы сделать полную копию упомянутой таблицы для менеджеров. Теперь прорабатываю варианты, как можно сделать. Появилась идея написать скрипт, который бы делал полную копию для каждого отдельного пользователя и который принимал бы на вход конкретного пользователя. идея сделать через меню показалась мне удачной.

Comment: @Марина, самое простое -- это брать Владельца Таблицы или читать настройку, как написано выше. Передача аргументов в меню не даст эффекта, кроме запутанного кода.

Comment: oshliaer спасибо за информацию и представленный код, буду разбираться!